# ip pim sparse-mode on Cisco 881-k9

Tags: switch

Fistly I am not a Cisco certified person but unfortunately i have to configure a Cisco router.
I am trying to configure multicasting with GRE over IPSec and I am stuck because my router ignores ip pim sparse mode commands.
I put ip multicast-routing somewhere in the config file.
My model is 881-k9, I couldn't find on the internet clear specification wheather it supports or not. 
Please assist.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a licensing issue based upon the information I found on the Cisco support forum.

https://supportforums.cisco.com/thread/2091010

Comment: You are right. We had to buy licence to activate this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I´m quite impressed... a non-cisco person going for a PIM over GRE?

Anyways, enable the PIM first (in the global config mode):
ip multicast-routing

then go to the Tunnel interface
config t
int Tunnel0

and try the "ip pim sparse-dense-mode" command

if it doesnt take it - no support on your 881, sorry.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, It's all working fine now :) The license was missing.